# Green line status changed bar does not showing in new Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I updated my VScode to version 1.87 and notice if I change my files/code there is no green bar appear in the left side of code screen, any one have idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: I find the solution , seems that Auto save file is not enable by default , if it enabled the status bar will be shown in the file. to enable it navigate to setting>Auto save and choose "onFocus change "